# How can i configure server in firebird.conf?

Tags: configuration, firebird

I want to connect an FDB database. However, no permission for all paths for this. And my FDB files are not in a path with permission. That's why  I wanna make some changes in firebird.conf for server configuration. Like here https://firebirdsql.org/rlsnotesh/config-fb-conf.html

As suggested, I have added the path of (.FDB) databases in DatabaseAccess and ExternalFileAccess. However, it didn't work yet. Is there anything else that I missed?

I use ubuntu.

-firebird.conf

```
DatabaseAccess = None
DatabaseAccess = Restrict C:\DataBase
DatabaseAccess = Restrict C:\DataBase;D:\Mirror
DatabaseAccess = Restrict /Firebird4.0;/db
DatabaseAccess = Restrict /home/ubuntu/Firebird4.0;/db;/mnt/mirrordb
DatabaseAccess = Full

ExternalFileAccess = Restrict /home/ubuntu/Firebird4.0
```

Comment: Please provide more information about what problem you. For example, if you don't have the necessary file permissions, then no amount of changes to the firebird.conf are going to help you. These settings are purely about Firebird allowing you to use a filepath to connect, but if Firebird doesn't have the necessary file permissions, then modifying this is not going to help.

Comment: Also, if you have all these lines in your firebird.conf, then - if I'm not mistaken - the last one (`DatabaseAccess = Full`) wins, so you should have one and only one of each config option.